# CentOS6にvsftpdをインストール、設定後のftp接続エラーに関するご質問

Tags: linux, ftp, vsftpd

大変お世話になっております。

CentOS6にvsftpdをインストール後、以下の設定をした後にデスクトップからftp接続を試みると記載しているエラーがftpクライアントの下部に表示され、ファイル等が表示されるべきftpクライアントの右の箇所には何も表示されません。

以下の設定からどこを修正すれば、ftpに接続できるかお教え願いませんでしょうか。

//ssh接続後の各ファイルの設定

**vsftpdの設定**

```
[root@xxx-xxx-xxxxx ~]# vi /etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf

anonymous_enable=NO
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
local_umask=022
dirmessage_enable=YES
xferlog_enable=YES
connect_from_port_20=YES
xferlog_std_format=YES
ascii_upload_enable=YES
ascii_download_enable=YES
chroot_local_user=YES
chroot_list_enable=YES
chroot_list_file=/etc/vsftpd/chroot_list
ls_recurse_enable=YES
listen=YES
pam_service_name=vsftpd
userlist_enable=YES
tcp_wrappers=YES
use_localtime=YES
userlist_deny=NO
userlist_file=/etc/vsftpd/user_list
pasv_enable=YES
pasv_min_port=60001
pasv_max_port=60030
```

**iptablesの設定**

```
[root@xxx-xxx-xxxxx ~]# vi /etc/sysconfig/iptables

# Firewall configuration written by  system-config-firewall
# Manual customization of this file is not recommended.
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
-A INPUT -m state --state  ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p  tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 20 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 21 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 60001:60030 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp- host-prohibited
-A FORWARD -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
COMMIT
```

**iptablesの稼働状況**

```
[root@xxx-xxx-xxxxx ~]# iptables -vnL
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0  bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in      out     source               destination
  780 97836 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *        0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
   78  5784 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
   17  1000 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state NEW tcp dpt:22
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0             state NEW tcp dpt:20
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0             state NEW tcp dpt:21
    1    40 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state NEW tcp dpts:60001:60030
    53  7216 REJECT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-host-prohibited

 Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  *      *         0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0             reject-with icmp-host-prohibited

 Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 921 packets, 150K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

//FFFTPでホスト一覧から、該当ホスト選択、設定変更クリック、ホストの設定ウィンドウの以下の各タブではその下に記載されているものがチェックされています。

```
拡張タブ
PASVモードを使う(V)

高度タブ
LISTコマンドでファイル一覧を取得(L)
可能であればMLSDコマンドで一覧を取得(M)

暗号化コマンド
暗号化なしで接続を許可
FTPS(Explicit)で接続
```

//デスクトップからftp接続をした際のエラー

```
FTP over Implicit SSL/TLS (FTPIS)を使用します.
ホスト 1xx.xxx.x.1xx (21) に接続しています.
接続しました.
接続できません.
FTP over Explicit SSL/TLS (FTPES)を使用します.
ホスト 1xx.xxx.x.1xx (21) に接続しています.
接続しました.
220 (vsFTPd 2.2.2)
>AUTH TLS
530 Please login with USER and PASS.
ログインできません.
通信は暗号化されていません.
第三者にパスワードおよび内容を傍受される可能性があります.
ホスト 1xx.xxx.x.1xx (21) に接続しています.
接続しました.
220 (vsFTPd 2.2.2)
>USER root
331 Please specify the password.
>PASS [xxxxxx]
230 Login successful.
>FEAT
211-Features:
EPRT
EPSV
MDTM
PASV
REST STREAM
SIZE
TVFS
UTF8
211 End
>OPTS UTF8 ON
200 Always in UTF8 mode.
>XPWD
257 "/"
>TYPE A
200 Switching to ASCII mode.
>PASV
227 Entering Passive Mode   (1xx,xxx,x,1xx,xxx,xxx).
ダウンロードのためにホスト 1xx.xxx.x.1xx (60016) に接続しています.
接続できません.
ファイル一覧の取得を中止しました.
ファイル一覧の取得に失敗しました.
```

*以下のIPアドレスはvsftpdがインストールされたリモートサーバーのアドレスです。
1xx.xxx.x.1xx

追記：
vsftpd.confのPASV関連の設定は変えずに、//FFFTPでホスト一覧から、該当ホスト選択、設定変更クリック、ホストの設定ウィンドウの拡張タブ下のPASVモードを使う(V)のチェックを外して試すと、ftpの接続エラーがなくりますが、

ファイルを転送すると以下のエラーが表示され、ファイルを転送できません。

拡張タブ
PASVモードを使う(V)　<--チェックを外して試す。

```
211 End
>OPTS UTF8 ON
200 Always in UTF8 mode.
>TYPE I
200 Switching to Binary mode.
>PORT xxx,xxx,x,xxx,xxx,xx <-----デスクトップのIPアドレスです。
200 PORT command successful. Consider using PASV.
>STOR /user.js
425 Failed to establish connection.
コマンドが受け付けられません.
アップロードを中止しました.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

認証には(暗号化なしで)成功していますが、データポート(60016番)への接続に失敗しています。
以下の理由が考えられます。

- (A) iptables または経路上のファイアーウォール等で 60001-60030 番ポートが拒否されている。
- (B) FTPクライアントがデータポートへ暗号化通信しようとして失敗している。

(A)→FTPクライアントから接続した回数分、"iptables -nvL" の 60001-60030 番ポート許可ルールの pkts が増えていくようであれば、許可されています。
pkts が増えないのであれば、経路上のファイアーウォール等の可能性が考えられます。

(B)→
vsftpd のデフォルトでは ssl_enable=NO で SSL/TLS が無効になっていますので、有効にするか、FTPクライアント側で暗号化通信を無効にして試してみてください。

Comment: Taichi Yanagiya様、ご教授頂きまして感謝致します。(A)の経路上のファイアーウォールに関しては具体的にどのように設定・修正すればよろしいのでしょうか？

Answer (score 0):

Taichi Yanagiya様のご教授、そして以下リンク先の「(3) SSL/TLSの設定」を行うことにより、接続できました。

[CentOS 6.3でFTPサーバーを構築（vsftpd)](https://ufuso.jp/wp/centos-6-3%E3%81%A7ftp%E3%82%B5%E3%83%BC%E3%83%90%E3%83%BC%E3%82%92%E6%A7%8B%E7%AF%89%EF%BC%88vsftpd/)

```
[root@xxx-xxx-xxxxx ~]#cd /etc/pki/tls/certs　←　certsディレクトリへ移動

[root@xxx-xxx-xxxxx ~] req -x509 -nodes -newkey rsa:1024 -keyout /etc/pki/tls/certs/vsftpd.pem -out /etc/pki/tls/certs/vsftpd.pem

Country Name (2 letter code) [XX]:JP　←　サーバーのある国名を入力してエンター・キーを押す（以下同じ）
State or Province Name (full name) []:Okinawa　←　都道府県名
Locality Name (eg, city) [Default City]:Naha　←　市区町村名
Organization Name (eg, company) [Default Company Ltd]:ShikakiraCS　←　組織名（ホスト名も可）
Organizational Unit Name (eg, section) []:　←　部課名（無入力もOK）
Common Name (eg, your name or your server's hostname) []:ufuso.dip.jp　←　ホスト名
Email Address []:tu@ufuso.dip.jp　←　障害時等の連絡先メールアドレス

[root@xxx-xxx-xxxxx ~]# chmod 600 vsftpd.pem　←　ファイルへの外部アクセス禁止

[root@xxx-xxx-xxxxx ~]# vi /etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf

//追記
ssl_enable=YES
force_local_data_ssl=NO
force_local_logins_ssl=NO
rsa_cert_file=/etc/pki/tls/certs/vsftpd.pem
```